# Selenium, Xpath hidden by Js

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

I have problem with js element on the website. Selenium does not see my xpath because as I suppose this element is hidden behind Js

I've used 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable....
[When I want check this element I can't. I see js. on map.
Of course I've found this element by (Firebug,firepath) but Selenium does not see and can't click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQRE8.png)

```html
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[6]"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[16]")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[16]")).click();
```

This element Selenium does not see.

```html
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]/div[2]")));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
```

Comment: I think you may need to provide a code example to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various possibilities.

1) Maybe your element has the `opacity`attribute set to 0, so you can set it to 1 through jQuery and make it visible:

```
WebDriver driver = new YOUR_DRIVER();
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('YOUR_ELEMENT').css('opacity','1');");
}
```

2) When you have to click on your element, you can change his `z-index` value to be "the most visible" in the page:

```
WebDriver driver = new YOUR_DRIVER();
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('YOUR_ELEMENT').css('z-index','100');");
}
```

3) You can hide your JS.

...